# Animation for the back button in a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

I have a class that extends DialogFragment, and I would like to add animation when the user presses the back button from that fragment

```
public class myClass extends DialogFragment{

    private void myAnimation(){
         // code here for animation...
    }
}
```

How can I call myAnimation() when the user presses the back button from this fragment?

Answer (score 0):

There are many animation you can choose for here take a look below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <translate
       android:fromXDelta="0"
       android:toXDelta="100%p"
       android:duration="500"
       android:repeatCount="1"
       android:repeatMode="reverse"/> //File name is anim_translate.xml
</set>

final Animation animTranslate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_translate)

Button btnTranslate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.translate);

   btnTranslate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
   view.startAnimation(animTranslate);
  }});
```

Take a look at this site [AndroidAnimation](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add animations into FragmentTransaction by method **setCustomAnimations (int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)** which is used to show DialogFragment(**DialogFragment.show(transaction, tag)**
).And you also need to invoke the method **addToBackStack(tag)** to make popExit animation avaliable.

So when you clicked the back button,it will automatically play the animation you have assigned(popExit animation).

Check the **setCustomAnimations**  method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Comment: Should that be added to the onCreatView method? And what do you mean by tag? Also, what is tag (the argument that addToBackStack takes in)?

Comment: That(FragmentTransaction's method) should be used in activity' s onCreate() to add fragment into layout programmatically.And when you add fragment to activity's layout programmatically,tag is just like the unique id of the fragment which you can get the instance of what you added throw FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tag) in further.The class name of your custom fragment could be used as the tag.

Comment: For more details about fragment,please refer this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)